# Common type for generic classes of different types

Tags: c#, generics, where-clause

I have (for example) Dictionary of different generic types (`d1, d2, d3, d4`) and I want to store them in ***something***

```
        var d1 = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        var d2 = new Dictionary<int, long>();
        var d3 = new Dictionary<DateTime, bool>();
        var d4 = new Dictionary<string, object>();


        var something = ???  //new List<object> {d1, d2, d3, d4};
```

Is there any other way how to store that in ***something*** with common denominator different than `object`?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `List<IDictionary>` since [`Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) implements `IDictionary`.

Alternatively, you could also use either `ICollection` or `IEnumerable` since they are also both interfaces implemented by the generic dictionary collection.